# Group rows by ID in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to create a pivot query to display survey response data from database.

Here is my query so far:

```
declare
    @columns     nvarchar(max) ='',
    @sql         nvarchar(max) = '',
    @responseIDs nvarchar(max) = '';

select
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(QuestionLabel) + ','
from
    SurveyQuestions
where
    SurveyID=1
order by
    QuestionSort;

set @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns)-1);
set @responseIDs = (select ResponseIDs from SurveyCart where SurveyCartID=7);

set @sql='
select * from ( 
    select 
        QuestionLabel, ResponseAnswer, ResponseID, AmountPaid = 
        (
            IIF(QuestionTypeID=2 and ResponseAnswer=''Yes'', QuestionValue, 0) +
            IIF(QuestionTypeID=6 and CAST(ResponseAnswer as int)>0, QuestionValue*Cast(ResponseAnswer as int), 0)
        )
    from 
        SurveyQuestions q
        inner join SurveyResponseAnswers ra 
            on q.QuestionID=ra.QuestionID
    where
        ResponseID in (' + @responseIDs + ')
) t
pivot(
    MAX(ResponseAnswer) for QuestionLabel in (' + @columns + ')
) as pivot_table;';

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Here are the results I get

```
ResponseID  AmountPaid  Attending?  Select     Cost with Quantities
19          0.00            NULL    Option 3   NULL
20          0.00            NULL    Option 1    
19          25.00           Yes     NULL       NULL
20          25.00           Yes     NULL       NULL
19          30.00           NULL    NULL       3
```

The Results I want:

```
ResponseID  AmountPaid  Attending?  Select     Cost with Quantities
19          55.00           Yes     Option 3   3
20          25.00           Yes     Option 1
```

I want there to be only one row for each response ID and where there are blank spots in Attending and Cost With quantities I need the results from the bottom rows and the amounts to be added together based on ResponseID.

Comment: It would help with actual data inserts to test with, and the actual output that you want.  But given your description so far, you probably have to use a GROUP BY ResponseID and SUM the amounts, with MIN/MAX on the other columns.

Comment: I think you just get rid of the pivot and use a simple `group by`. You're already hard-coding `QuestionTypeId` values is there really any need to make the `ResponseID`s dynamic. Either way just wrap up the column expressions with `case` or `if` kind of like you already did.

Comment: I need the pivot because I'm creating columns out of the QuestionLabels which are in a different table from the Responses

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    ResponseID,
    sum(case when QuestionLabel = 'AmountPaid' then
        iif(QuestionTypeID = 2 and ResponseAnswer = 'Yes', QuestionValue, 0) +
        iif(QuestionTypeID = 6 and cast(ResponseAnswer as int) > 0,
            QuestionValue * Cast(ResponseAnswer as int), 0)
    end) as "AmountPaid",
    min(case when QuestionLabel = 'Attending?'
        then ResponseAnswer end) as "Attending?",
    min(case when QuestionLabel = 'Select'
        then ResponseAnswer end) as "Select",
    min(case when QuestionLabel = 'Cost with quantities'
        then ResponseAnswer end) as "Cost with Quantities"
from 
    SurveyQuestions q
    inner join SurveyResponseAnswers ra 
        on q.QuestionID = ra.QuestionID
where ResponseID in (
    select ResponseIDs from SurveyCart where SurveyCartID = 7
);
```

I don't understand exactly what a "Question Value" or a "Survey Cart" is but I think this should be close. Unless you expect the question labels to change in the future I don't see why you can't just hard-code them here as you've already done with a number of ID values.

Comment: The question labels will be different because users can make their own surveys and forms with whatever questions. That's why it has to be dynamic.